How does Masstransit heartbeat and session timeout works?
We have an application which is receiving around 60k messages per partition in a single topic(Total partition is 10) once in a day within 5 minutes. With Masstransit consumer we are using default settings for checkpoint message count(5000) and interval (1 min). I observed that our consumer goes in rebalancing issues with "client reason: not provided". Our consumer has only instance running here since we are testing right now in UAT. According to what I understand, Masstransit checks every 1 min if message count consumed are 5000 then it commits the offsets but the consumer never reaches 5000 and it goes in a loop since offsets are not committed. I checked the kafka native configuration for heartbeat which is every 3 seconds, session timeout every 45 seconds and max poll records 500 with max poll interval 5 mins. We are seeing all these settings are matched based on the consumer logs but still rebalancing is happening. Do we know how can we troubleshoot this?

The checkpoint settings are configurable, both the time and the message count. Seems like you need to make some adjustments downwards to better suit your workload.

Thanks for the quick reply. Thing is even if rebalance happens it should commit offsets with whatever is already consumed right? And it does normally but when we have issues like "Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException: Broker: Unknown member"  it doesnt commit offsets hence we are in a loop. I am sure whether the issue here is if bus is not able to exit gracefully though we did configure consume stoptimeout configuration. Any comments here?

No comment, Kafka can be cruel sometimes in how it nukes consumers that aren't responding within the timeouts.
